# Git Branch has no head tag in Sourcetree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I notice there is no Head tag for the branch I am working on in SourceTree.
What would cause that and how do I fix it?

.git\HEAD contains

```
ref: refs/heads/Kirsten
```

The Sourcetree version was 2.3.1.0 when I noticed the issue and I have just updated to 2.4.8.0

Another strange thing, I am not seeing the 3 branches in the tree. Only 2.
[image]

Maybe the issue is to do with working on the Kirsten branch from 2 different machines.

I see there is an Orign\Head tag.  Is there no need for a different Head tag?

Comment: You could try checking out the branch again?

Comment: Checking out Kirsten again is disabled. I tried checking out Aparna and then Kirsten but it made no difference.

Comment: Can you view the contents of the file `repoRoot/.git/HEAD`? If so, what does it say?

Comment: Yes. I updated the question to show it.

Comment: Then the issue looks like it lies with SourceTree. Maybe restart it?

Comment: How do I restart it?

Comment: Turn it off and on again?

Comment: The computer?  I have done that often enough.

Comment: I meant the program. Hmmm. I think you’ll need to contact the program’s creators.

Comment: About the three branches not being visible -- I see branch `Kirsten` at line 1 and branches `master` and `Aparna` on line 4 in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe there is only one Head tag. origin/Head
I just stumbled through creating a new repository and here is the graph

[image]

Comment: `origin/HEAD` and `HEAD` are two different things. `origin/HEAD` is where the `HEAD` ref was at at the remote called `origin` the last time you fetched. `HEAD` is on the commit or branch you currently have checked out locally. Perhaps SourceTree hides the local one by design.

Comment: @jsageryd, seems you're correct - local HEADs in SourceTree are only shown if they're detached.